# Is it possible in Python to declare that method must be overridden?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, methods, overriding

I have an "abstract" class, such as:

```
class A:
    def do_some_cool_stuff():
        ''' To override '''
        pass

    def do_some_boring_stuff():
        return 2 + 2
```

And class B, subclassing A:

```
class B(A):
    def do_stuff()
        return 4
```

Is there any way to declare, that a method `A.do_some_cool_stuff` *must* be overriden, and, possibly that some warning should be raised while trying to create B-class object, when B had not implemented `A.do_some_cool_stuff`?

Comment: See also https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47059/raising-error-if-method-not-overridden-by-sub-class. It is a critique of the `raise NotImplementedError("Subclass responsibility")` approach which I was about to suggest here.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, by defining `A` as an [ABC (Abstract Base Class)](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def do_some_cool_stuff():
        ''' To override '''
        pass

    def do_some_boring_stuff():
        return 2 + 2
```

You can subclass `A`, but you can only create instances of such a subclass if the `do_some_cool_stuff()` method has a concrete implementation:

```
>>> from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
>>> class A(ABC):
...     @abstractmethod
...     def do_some_cool_stuff():
...         ''' To override '''
...         pass
...     def do_some_boring_stuff():
...         return 2 + 2
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def do_stuff():
...         return 4
... 
>>> B()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods do_some_cool_stuff
```

Comment: Is `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta` necessary?

Comment: @RTD not in recent Python versions, but you want to then inherit from `abc.ABC`. I’ve adjusted the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Wondering why to inherit because it looks like using `@abstractmethod` decorators does the job? i.e., a subclass can't be instantiated unless all abstract methods are overridden first. Can you clarify what ABC inheritance adds please?

Comment: @RTD: no, `@abstractmethod` decorators are only part of the process. The `ABC` base class brings in the `ABCMeta` metaclass, and that takes care of gathering marked names into a frozenset of names to verify as implemented. See the [Pure Python fallback implementation of `ABCMeta.__new__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/985a71032bf055240e61259285a0b4925c925383/Lib/_py_abc.py#L35-L52), which builds the `__abstractmethods__` for each class (this is called for each subclass created). You can't create instances of a class with a non-empty `__abstractmethods__` value.